# 32 bit adder subtractor ALU using generate

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I need to implement a 32 bit adder subtractor ALU for a class assignment. I have a 1-bit adder subtractor that works fine and the operation is made with the help of a select statement (code for all is given below). Anyway, the problem I am facing is that I am unable to figure out how to use the carry/borrow out of one module to the subsequent module.

```
module add_sub(select, i0, i1, cin, out, cout
    );

input i0, i1, select, cin;
output out, cout;
wire y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6;
wire z0, z1, z2, z3, z4;

//diff = i0 xor i1 xor cin
//borrow = cin. ~(i1 xor i2) or ~x.y

xor (y0, i1, cin);
xor (y1, i0, y0); //y1=diff or sum as only carry and borrow vary between adder and subtractor circuits

xor (y2, i1, i0);
and (y3, cin, ~y2);
and (y4, ~i0, i1);
or (y6, y5, y4); //y6 = borrow

and (z0, i0, i1);
xor (z1, i0, i1);
and (z2, cin, z1);
or (z3, z0, z2); //z3= carry out for sum

//conditional operator for assigning sum or difference. if select = 0, we add, else subtract

assign out = y1;
assign cout = select ? y6 : z3;

endmodule
```

This module is instantiated in a loop in the alu module that is given below...

```
module alu(sel, num1, num2, alu_cin, alu_out, alu_c
    );


parameter N = 32;
input sel; //select line for add or sub
input [N-1:0] num1; //two inputs
input [N-1:0] num2;
input alu_cin;

output [N-1:0] alu_out; //32 bit output
output alu_c;            // becomes final carry or borrow accordingly

genvar i;

generate for (i=0; i<=N-1; i=i+1) 

    begin: alu_loop

        if (i == 0)
            add_sub as_i (sel, num1[i], num2[i], alu_cin, alu_out[i], alu_c);
        else
            add_sub as_i (sel, num1[i], num2[i], alu_loop[i-1].as_i.cout[i-1], alu_out[i], alu_c);
    end

endgenerate   




endmodule
```

In the test bench for the alu, I gave appropriate 32 bit values and the select value as I need. The problem comes with

```
add_sub as_i (sel, num1[i], num2[i], alu_loop[i-1].as_i.cout[i-1], alu_out[i], alu_c);
```

It says "Indexing cannot be applied to a scalar." as I am trying to simulate it. Syntax check is completed perfectly.

I need access to cout from the one-bit module to pass it on as cin to the next one. The alu_c can be overwritten as only the last one bit is needed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :) All this is done on Xilinx ISE through Verilog modules.

Answer (score 2):

It is syntactically correct but you are using a bit-select on a single bit value, which is a semantic error.

```
add_sub as_i (
  sel,num1[i],num2[i],alu_loop[i-1].as_i.cout[i-1],alu_out[i],alu_c);
                                         ^^^^
```

Declared as scalar output in add_sub

```
output out, cout;
```

While Verilog allows referencing a port using the dot notation(hierarchical referencing), it's not a good practice outside of testbenches. You should declare a wire for that connectivity instead.

```
for (i=0; i<=N-1; i=i+1) 
  begin: alu_loop
    wire cout; // Visible as alu_loop[N].cout 
  end
```